# Parse HTML to Plain Text

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the MLStripper class that I found recommended on several postings to strip out the html from an email in order to get plain text.  The strip_tags function runs into an issue when trying to parse  due to the "@" sign.  I guess this class is not powerful enough to only parse valid html tags, any recommendations on how to fix the below to handle the "@" or another library to remove html from text?  I need to also remove things like & as well.

**Python:**

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
            def __init__(self):
                 self.reset()
                 self.fed = []
            def handle_data(self, d):
                 self.fed.append(d)
            def get_data(self):
                 return ''.join(self.fed)

            def strip_tags(self, html):
                 s = MLStripper()
                 s.feed(html)
                 return s.get_data()

 ML = MLStripper()
 test = ML.strip_tags("<div><br>On Sep 27, 2012, at 4:11 PM, Mark Smith <marksmith@gmail.com> wrote</br></div>")
 print test
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IMAPReader.py", line 49, in <module>
    strippedText = ML.strip_tags("<marksmith@gmail.com>")
  File "IMAPReader.py", line 22, in strip_tags
    s.feed(html)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 108, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 148, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 229, in parse_starttag
    endpos = self.check_for_whole_start_tag(i)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 304, in check_for_whole_start_tag
    self.error("malformed start tag")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 115, in error
    raise HTMLParseError(message, self.getpos())
HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 1, column 9
```

Answer (score 3):

If you expect to get invalid markup, you don't want an HTML parser. Check out BeautifulSoup:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

They have a nice example of doing exactly what you want to do:

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>

<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

print(soup.get_text())
```

returns...

```
# The Dormouse's story
#
# The Dormouse's story
#
# Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
# Elsie,
# Lacie and
# Tillie;
# and they lived at the bottom of a well.
#
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python are you using?  I ran your code using Python 2.7.2 and I got the same error you did.  Then later I ran it on a computer with **Python 2.7.3** and it works perfectly.  This was pretty strange so I looked it up and some documentation I found said the HTML parser included with Python became more lenient in the later version.  Try upgrading to 2.7.3 and it should work.